# Variable timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm living in Belgium and I'm looking how to change timezone in PHP depending om the date of the year.

From 30 March until 25 October the timezone is UTC+2.00 from 26 October to 29 March it's UTC+1.00.

User put in a date (where the event will be booked).

The format for this date is y-m-d (like 2015-07-07)

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['date'];
$sDate= date('m-d', strtotime($date));
$SummerStart = date('m-d', strtotime("03-30"));
$SummerEnd = date('m-d', strtotime("10-26"));

if (($sDate > $SummerStart) && ($sDate < $SummerEnd))
{
  echo "Between";
}
else
{
  echo "Not between";  
}
?>
```

To change the timezone in summer from UTC+2.00 to UTC+01.00 I need to check if the date( month and day) given by the user is between the 2 values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are defining time in a wrong way, trying to print out your varaiables, gives the following values:

```
echo "SummerStart -->".$SummerStart ." SummerEnd -->".$SummerEnd;
```

> SummerStart -->12-31 SummerEnd -->12-31

12-31 is a sign by PHP that something is wrong with your date logic

But this should work for you:

```
$date = date('m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']);
$summer_start = date('m-d', strtotime("0000-03-30"));
$summer_end = date('m-d', strtotime("0000-10-26"));

if (($date > $summer_start) && ($date < $summer_end))
{
    echo "Between";
}
else
{
    echo "Not between";  
 }
```